# Angular 13: Radio [checked] not working with formControlName

Tags: angular, forms, radio-button, formgroups

I am using a simple `FormGroup` to set a checked value to a radio, but it simply does not work. It works from the front-page to the code, but not from the code to the front-page.

HTML:

```
   <form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline mt-2">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" formControlName="radioValue1"
             id="radioStopLossNone" [checked]="radioModel.value1==1"
             value="1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="radioStopLossNone">None</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" formControlName="radioValue1"
             id="radioStopLossFixed" [checked]="radioModel.value1==2"
             value="2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="radioStopLossFixed">Value-1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" formControlName="radioValue1"
             id="radioStopLossTrailing" [checked]="radioModel.value1==3"
             value="3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="radioStopLossTrailing">Value-2</label>
    </div>
   </form>
```

Model:

```
export class Model {
   value1: number;
}
```

TS:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.model = new Model();
  this.model.value1 = 1;

  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    radioValue1: [model.value1, [Validators.required]],
  });
  this.f.radioValue1.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('radioValue1: ' + this.f.radioValue1.value);
  });
}
```

Now, if I remove the `formControlName` tag from the `radio` controls, then it starts reading the code and checking the `radios` from code to front-page, but disables the link from front-page to code. How can I get them both working at the same time?

Thank you.

**SOLUTION:**
I followed the recommendations of @rohithpoya to remove the `checked` attribute from the `HTML` and to use the same Data Type in the model and it worked.

```
<input type="radio" formControlName="radioValue1" value="2"> // value is string
```

`value='2'` is set as `string`, then in the model I used:

```
this.model.value1 = '1'; // value here is string too
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  radioValue1: [model.value1, [Validators.required]],
});
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Also, you have all three checkboxes under the same formControlName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the checked attribute. Actually, if you have the value in the form control, it should automatically be selected. If it doesn't work, you need to check the type of the value.In template you defined value as number and please confirm that you have number type in form control also.

Also I can see that you didn't declare the *radioModel* in ts file. Therefore instead of *radioModel*, try using *model*.

**UPDATE**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.radioModel = new Model();
  this.radioModel.value1 = 1;

  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    radioValue1: [model.value1, [Validators.required]],
  });
  this.f.radioValue1.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('radioValue1: ' + this.f.radioValue1.value);
  });
}
```

Use this in ts file.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please exemplify?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You're not correctly getting `radioValue1`

Use this code :

HTML :

```html
<div class="form-check form-check-inline mt-2">

    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" formControlName="radioValue1" 
         [checked]="radioModel.value1 === 1" [value]="1">
    
    <label class="form-check-label" for="radioStopLossNone">None</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-check-inline">

    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" formControlName="radioValue1" 
        [checked]="radioModel.value1 === 2" [value]="2">
    
    <label class="form-check-label" for="radioStopLossFixed">Value-1</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" formControlName="radioValue1"  
        [checked]="radioModel.value1 === 3" [value]="3">
    
    <label class="form-check-label" for="radioStopLossTrailing">Value-2</label>
    
</div>
```

TS :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.model = new Model();
  this.model.value1 = 1;

  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    radioValue1: [model.value1, [Validators.required]],
  });
  
  this.myForm.controls["radioValue1"].valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    this.model.value1 = this.myForm.controls["radioValue1"].value;
    console.log('radioValue1: ' + this.myForm.controls["radioValue1"].value);
  });
}
```

In the TS code you get the form control value by using
`myForm.controls["radioValue1"]` and do operations on it.

In HTMl code you set input values by `[value]` attribute not reqular `value' attribute.

And correctly check if it matches by changing `==` to `===`

Comment: **not** use `[checked]`, just only `formControlName`